# How to check whether a zip file or compressed file is exist?

Tags: c++, fstat

If i dont know whether a file is exist.If it exist i will do something depend on the content in that file.The file could be in .txt or .gz format and the file can also not exist. 
Below is my code:

```
      //Check whether is a zip file
      char *pre_pcom_file_copy = new char[strlen(pre_pat_file)+7];
      strcpy (pre_pcom_file_copy,pre_pcom_file);
      strcat (pre_pcom_file_copy,".gz");
      char *cmd = new char[strlen("gzip -dc ")+strlen(pre_pcom_file_copy)+1];
      strcpy (cmd,"gzip -dc ");
      strcat (cmd,pre_pcom_file_copy);
      if ( (pre_pcom = popen(cmd,"r")) == NULL ){
          //Do nothing
      }else{
          cout << "Parsing pre.pcomments file   --->" << pre_pcom_file << endl;
          pcomyyin = pre_pcom;
          if(_vecTime.size() > 0){
              //for pre_pcom _vecTime should be empty
              pcom_time = _vecTime[_vecTime.size()-1];
          }
          first_time = 1; // make sure tester cycle start from 0 from pcomment file
          pcomyyparse ();
          pclose(pre_pcom);
          //delete [] cmd;
          cout << "Parsing pre.pcomments file DONE!" << endl;
      }
```

I want to check a file that has the same name with a must have file for example hello.abc but the file i want to check could be hello.abc or hello.gz or even not exist.If i do in the way like above i got error when the file hello.txt or hello.gz are totally not exist.How can i solve this?

Comment: This is C++. Why is it tagged `C`?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Because i make use of c++ and c so i tagged both.or i must put only c++?

Comment: They're [different languages](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/38942/how-is-c-different-from-c). If you're using `cout << ...` then you're writing C++ and not C.

Answer (score 2):

Just call fstat() on the various possible names and check the resulting error if any.

Comment: could you show me an example with code?if i want to test abc.gz is exist?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a POSIX system (like Linux, BSD or OSX) then you can use [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) to see if a file exists. On Windows use [`PathFileExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Or use the [Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library, like its [`exists`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#exists) function.

Comment: On windows there's also [`_stat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx).